# Как очистить dict не полностью, а только значения в ключах?

Tags: python

Хотел узнать как очистить значения в ключах в dict, не удаляя от туда ключи. Методом clear не получиться, так как он очистит полностью.

Comment: `dict` без значений - это `set`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что означает «очистить», но вот так можно присвоить ключам пустую строку:

```
for key in dictionary:
    dictionary[key] = ""
```

Comment: Я имел ввиду что бы dict после очистки не был пустим, а в нем сохранилися все ключи, а очистились только значения которые храняться в этих ключах. Но спасибо ваш метот помог

Comment: `dictionary[key] = None` - присвоение "пустого" значения.